# iOS Label Visibility toggle not animating

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to toggle the visibility of a UILabel based on a Tap Gesture on an UIImageView. The code that performs the toggling is as follows:

```
func imageTapped(img: UIImageView) {
    print(photoTitle.hidden)
    if (photoTitle.hidden) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.photoTitle.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.photoTitle.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    self.photoTitle.hidden = !self.photoTitle.hidden
}
```

The issue with this is that it seems to ignore the animation on the second tap i.e. to hide the UILabel again. It just becomes invisible instead of animating gradually. In the viewdDidLoad(), I initialize the photoTitle.hidden = true to be invisible initially.

Any glaring mistakes?

Comment: The statement self.photoTitle.hidden = !self.photoTitle.hidden is executed before executed the statement of your block.

Comment: If it is just to hide the label then you should be using only the alpha of that label rather than using the hidden property also, alpha would give you the effect also

Comment: If you have any reason to hide the label, it is enough using only `alpha` to hide it. don't use `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `self.photoTitle.hidden = true` into the completion block of your else condition

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change the function like this

**Swift 2**

```
func imageTapped(img: UIImageView) {
    print(photoTitle.hidden)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.photoTitle.alpha = self.photoTitle.alpha < 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func imageTapped(img: UIImageView) {
    print(photoTitle.hidden)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.photoTitle.alpha = self.photoTitle.alpha < 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yea, that worked. I don't understand what is wrong with my code though. Could you explain?

Comment: Your code changed the hidden state for the label before the animation does it's part, as duration for animation is 0.5 seconds, meanwhile this "self.photoTitle.hidden = !self.photoTitle.hidden" instruction executes

Answer (score 0):

`hidden`  doesn't work on this animation, you can instead of `alpha`